# counting source code lines in python project

Tags: python, version-control, code-metrics

How do I calculate the number of lines written in a project containing multiple sub dirs in a python project. for example a dir structure is like

```
A  
 \ <*some files here*>\  
  B  
   \ <*some files here*>\ ... and so on...
```

Comment: [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the find utility in linux.

On the command prompt:

```
$ find <project_directory_path> -name '*.py' | xargs wc -l
```

This will give you the count of all files ending with .py in the project_directory and finally the total. (I am assuming you just want the count of .py files)

If you just want the total and nothing else, you could use:

```
$ find <project_directory_path> -name '*.py' | xargs wc -l | tail -1
```

Comment: That will not give you the total but just for individual files.

Comment: You're right, slipped my mind that -exec works on the individual file and will not provide a total (unless we use some nasty awk).